# Cell in Cellular communication

Tags: communication, telephone, cellphone

When they talk about the "cell" in cellular communication, they often refer to the shape of hexagon. If I am correct, this is probably the coverage area of the transmission base tower. SHouldn't be circular shape instead?

Answer (score 7):

The theoretical coverage area of a given cellular (or other UHF) transmitter will be circular, if it uses an omni-directional antenna - but most of the cell sites I've seen have multiple directional antennas, so the actual coverage area may have a non-circular shape.  Buildings and other obstructions may also alter the shape of the coverage area.

When making a conceptual drawing of multiple cell cites, it is common to show each cell's coverage as a hexagon, as that results in the most compact "packing" of cell sites.  In practice, cell sites can't be placed in a perfect hexagonal pattern, but that pattern works well for general discussions of the cell system.

Comment: More to the point, there's a boundary between any two cell towers where the signal power from each tower is the same. This boundary is a straight line that's perpendicular to a line connecting the towers. On either side of this boundary, you communicate with the nearest tower. When you have a hexagonal grid of towers, these boundaries form hexagons. Put another way, for any given tower, the set of places for which it is the nearest (strongest) tower relative to any other is a hexagon.

Comment: @DaveTweed Why it can't be octagon??

Comment: Octagon's can't repeat without overlapping... even if octagons were used and overlapping were created, the "negating" of the power output would revert it back to hexagons as per Dave Tweed's comment above...